# Optimizing a Dwarven Rogue 7 for front-line combat in a tank-free party

Tags: dnd-3.5e, optimization, rogue, character-advancement

Started playing D&D with a new group and got 7 levels into my Dwarf Rogue before deciding I didn't what to do next. I was up to now playing as a stealthy thief, two weapon fighter. But our combat encounters have been testing me a lot more lately since out main tank died, leaving one other melee character aside from me (a Swash).

I am just stuck with what I should do next, available content is the 3.5 books, include completes.  Nothing online or home brewed.

We had 72 points available, currently my stats are:

- Str 10
- Dex 20
- Con 17
- Int 12
- Wis 10
- Cha 10

Feats:

- TWF
- Weapon Finesse
- Rapid Assault (extra d6 damage at start of combat)
- +1 undecided yet

Current equipment:

- Pair of +2 daggers
- Standard leather armor
- +2 sneak boots (hide and move silently)

My original plan was to take Assassin prestige class, but now I'm thinking about taking some fighter dips for some extra hardiness. I ruled out Swordsage and Swashbuckler, because we have 2 Sorcs and a Swash, so I don't want to stack the party.

What class dips/feats/skills or type of equipment should I aim for to increase my combat capability. I am probably not going to be able to apply sneak attack more than once per fight so i'll need to be able to deal more damage/survive more.

Comment: This is very broad and impossible to answer with a "correct" answer. This site is not suited to generate long lists of possibly working alternatives. Can you narrow your question down for what you seek? More HP? More AC? Better saves?

Answer (score 2):

Have you considered Barbarian? The extra movement lets you reposition effectively, rage adds a decent chunk of hp and increases your daggers' damage a bit and the d12 HD can give a nice boost to your health. The extra BAB might make a buckler more appealing. You also continue to improve your *Trapsense*. The extra 2 skillpoints/level over a Fighter is also a boon.

Honestly though, you seem underequipped for a level 7 character.

Comment: The expected wealth of a 7-th level character is 23,500 gp. A +2 dagger costs 8,000 gp, and so the pair costs 16,000 gp. The boots probably cost about 800 gp, some with the miscellaneous we get 17,000 gp. So yes, under-equipped, and poorly equipped at that (ditch the +2 daggers, use 2 +1 daggers instead and buy something else with the remaining 12,000 gp).

Comment: We haven't gotten much loot or money.  I'm as well equipped as I can be

Comment: I do like the idea of a Barbarian dip though, only problem is the XP penalty, which is why I considered fighter.

Comment: Even +1 daggers of shock, frost or flaming would be a big dps boost over +2 daggers (average of 4.95 damage per dagger per hit to an average of 7.35 dpdph, not including sneak attacks or energy immunity/DR)

Answer (score 1):

In general, the "have a higher AC than the monsters can hit" strategy is very difficult at high levels.  Monster attack bonuses increase as you gain levels; your AC is mostly dependent on your stats and equipment, and does not increase unless you spend a lot of money on it.  If the monsters are hitting hard enough to kill the tank, it's going to be difficult or impossible for you to improve your own tanking abilities enough to survive.

(Which is not to say that you shouldn't try.  Perhaps you could trade that leather armor for a +1 [mithral shirt](http://www.dandwiki.com/wiki/SRD:Mithral_Shirt).  Also, it's traditional at your level to have a ring of protection +1 and an amulet of natural armor +1.)

Let's talk about magic solutions.  One thing that can work okay is to use a summoned monster as your tank.  Does one of your sorcerer friends have a *summon monster* spell they can cast?

As a rogue, you get huge benefits from *greater invisibility*.  One of those benefits is your full-round sneak attack; another benefit is that the monsters can't target you easily.  Your sorcerer friends can't cast this on you (yet), but consider getting a few scrolls for emergencies.  You can activate these with your *use magic device* skill, or just ask a sorcerer to read it for you.

As a rogue, you might get good benefit from an *anklet of translocation*, which costs 1400gp.  It lets you teleport ten feet as a swift action, twice per day.  You can use this either to attack from stealth (teleport from your hiding spot to a place where you can full-attack with sneak damage) or to run and hide if the combat gets too hot for you.  Unfortunately it takes a feet slot, which means it doesn't combine well with your boots.